# Stunning CGI short film about war and love where the leader of one world invades the other after being rejected

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, short-film

The story is about two people - both leaders of their respective species.  On one side, the tall, powerful looking male character, and a young, beautiful queen, who he is in love with.  After being rejected, he invades her world - a beautiful ring world, with its sun in the center.  After the world is evacuated he lands his craft near her palace, and at the same time she takes off her necklace, which is a replica of her world, and takes the sun out of the middle, which causes the real sun to die, and the world starts to freeze.

The film ends with the two of them standing in front of each other - they embrace, and die in each other's arms as the ice reaches them.

I also remember that it had a brilliant, moving soundtrack.

A little more information:  This was an animated short, which I came across on the internet, and it would have been 5 years ago at least.

Comment: Do you know what the run length was roughly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the short sci-fi film ***Nightfall*** from 2012.

> Once upon a time, somewhere in space... there was a huge ringworld and its articifial sun. A beautiful queen watched over this unique place. But one day, a dark lord falls in love with her. More than any other things in universe he desires the precious queen of the ring. He encircles her homeworld with his gigantic spacefleet and finally starts a direful attack with the only intention to conquer the beautiful queen for himself.

It ends as you described (she removes the sun from her necklace and they both freeze together). Its creator put it up on Youtube, and here it is:

Comment: "direful" - I thought that'd be one of those things like "irregardless" or "whomst", but turns out it is a real word.